# Django AttributeError: <Object> needs to have a hvalue for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django

**My issue:**

I'm trying to add some models to my database through the admin path on my django project, but this error keeps popping up when I try to create an instance of my model. The `clean` function exists to ensure that each Pokemon model can only have up to 2 types selected from a list of all possible types.

**My code:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator as min, MaxValueValidator as max
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class PokeType(models.Model):
    poke_type = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poke_type


#Current generation of games for gen_added field
gen = 8

class Pokemon(models.Model):
    poke_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    poke_type = models.ManyToManyField(PokeType, blank=True, null=True)
    evolves_from = False
    evolves_into = False
    gen_added = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[min(1), max(gen)])

     def clean(self):
         #Allow max of 2 poke_types to be selected
         if self.poke_type.count() > 2:
             raise ValidationError('A Pokemon has a maximum of two types.')


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Pokemon'
        abstract = True


class CustomPokemon(Pokemon):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    level = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**What I (kind of) know:**

Based on what I've seen from other people asking this question, I need to save the instance of my model before I can use the many-to-many relationship in the `clean` function. Also, I do not get the error when my `clean` function is commented out, so I've narrowed the issue down to that portion of the code.

**What I've tried:**

I thought that changing my if statement to check for the presence of the `poke_type` variable would help - i.e.

```
     def clean(self):
         #Allow max of 2 poke_types to be selected
         if self.poke_type and self.poke_type.count() > 2:
             raise ValidationError('A Pokemon has a maximum of two types.')
```

but the error is still raised. As I noted above, removing that function also allows me to proceed without raising that specific error, but breaks my ability to limit the max number of types selectable.

Next, I tried creating a `save` function to save the model and then give the model the `poke_type` attribute after that:

```
    def save(self):
        self.save()
        self.poke_type = models.ManyToManyField(PokeType, blank=True, null=True)
```

Is there a way to save the instance of the model as it's being added through the admin site or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the `m2m_changed` signal instead

```
def poke_type_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['instance'].poke_type.count() > 2:
        raise ValidationError('A Pokemon has a maximum of two types.')


m2m_changed.connect(poke_type_changed, sender=Pokemon.poke_type.through)
```

Comment: Ok, I imported the ```m2m_changed``` signal, but when I write out the code the way you've typed it, it raises a ```NameError: name Pokemon is not defined```. I tried indenting the ```m2m_changed...``` line so it's part of the function which allows the code to run without giving me the NameError, but it also acts as though that limiter does not exist. The code you've suggested is supposed to be part of the model ```Pokemon```, correct?

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. I was defining the function within the model ```Pokemon``` but after I moved the function definition and signal call outside and after the model definition, it seemed to work. Thank you for the information!